# in rails How to import from multiple stylesheets of single xlsx file into multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, import, xlsx

I have one xlsx file having 3 sheets.I want to import data of each sheet into different tables.Please Help me into this.

Comment: I got the answer after searching....

Comment: def  import
    ex = Roo::Spreadsheet.open("#{Rails.root}/details1.xlsx", file_warning: :ignore)
    ex.default_sheet = ex.sheets[0]
    (2..ex.last_row).each do |line|  
    name = ex.cell(line,'E')
    email = ex.cell(line,'B')
    contact = ex.cell(line,'C')
    @users = User.create(:name => name,:email => nil,:contact => nil)

    end

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to convert it to csv?

If possible, convert this xlsx file to 3 separated csv files (e.g `field delimeter = ,` `text delimiter = "` ).

Then, open your rails console (or create a .rb script), read each file with the CSV class and save the data on the table. Jump the first line if you have a header (`drop(1)`).

Example:

```
require 'csv'

CSV.foreach("sheet1.csv").drop(1) do |row|
  YourTable.create!({
    field_a: row[0],
    field_b: row[1],
    field_c: row[2]
  })
end
```

*PS: I don't know why people are downvoting this question. SO is suppose to be a place where programmers seek help. The downvoters could at least explain why they are down voting.*

Comment: I was just researching the meta for the best words, I'll add my comment shortly

Comment: It's actually on the hover in the down vote button "This question does not show any research effort;"